# Android Studio: Can't use previously created sign key file

Tags: android-studio, android-signing

Can't import previously created sign key file, please look at screenshot. There is no field for password. AS 3.2.1. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Did you tried restarting Android Studio?

Comment: @NirajNiroula sure, but with no effect

Comment: Solved by importing IDE settings of previous version. The issue is still unclear.